# PaperClip: one database entry for multiple file uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, jquery-file-upload

For example, I uploaded two files A and B in the same form, paperclip will insert two entries into the database.

Is there a way to force paperclip to create only one database entry and insert into two different fields (e.g. file_name_A, file_name_B, file_size_A, file_size_B....)?

**UPDATE**:

in my **submission.rb:**

```
attr_accessible :id, :email, :uploads_attributes
has_many :uploads, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :uploads, :allow_destroy => true
```

in my **upload.rb**:

```
belongs_to :submission
attr_accessible :id, :user_id, :package_a_file_name, :package_a_file_size, :package_b_file_name, :package_b_file_size, :updated_at
has_attached_file :package
```

Comment: How is your model set up? Doesn't paperclip just add fields to the model's table for each attachment - eg `attachment_file_name`, `attachment_2_file_name` etc?

Comment: @ChristianVarga, I only have one model but I am also using jQuery-file-upload to attach multiple files, link is here:https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: But how many files are we talking about? Just 2, like your example? Or do you actually mean you want your model to accept 0 to many files? I ask this because the answer is different depending on what you want to do.

Comment: @ChristianVarga, in my case, just 2 :)

Comment: Can you post the code for your model? Specifically the part for the attachments. If you want 2 files attached to the 1 model, you need to have 2 `has_attached_file` definitions.

Comment: @ChristianVarga, thanks for all the comments! I have attached the code in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the way your model is set up. Storing multiple uploads in a separate model makes it easier to maintain down the track, should you ever wish to change the requirements.

You've only specified *one* attached file in upload.rb, which is why it inserts a separate entry for each upload. Specifying random `attr_accessibles` won't do anything, those fields don't even exist.

You *could* remove the upload model altogether, and just store the uploads directly on the submission:

**submission.rb**

```
has_attached_file :package_a
has_attached_file :packabe_b
```

This would store the uploads in a single row, associated to the submission. This is not scalable.

I would not store multiple uploads in your upload model in an unscalable fashion as above, that wouldn't make logical sense from an OOP point of view.

All in all, I think the way you've got it set up now is the best approach.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Although it's not exactly what I am looking for. I have to use a nested model because I have two tables `submissions` and `uploads` and they are refered to each other by a foreign key, and users are supposed to upload two files at a time. Anyway, I have tried with the solution you provided (with the single  model) but it seems not to work either, it still gives me two entries, one with the "package_b_file_name" `null` and the other with the "package_a_file_name" `null`

Comment: If it's giving you 2 entries, you've got something massively misconfigured. Paperclip is trivial, you define the attached file, and add `form.file_field :attachment_name` for each attachment to the form, and that's that. But you've got custom stuff going on, so if you want help debugging, you'll have to explain exactly how you've got it set up, and provide all the relevant code for the models & form upload. Otherwise we have no idea what's happening.

Comment: New question with code snippet here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900711/paperclip-multiple-has-attached-file-in-one-model