# Paperclip: Multiple "has_attached_file" in one Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, paperclip

snippet from my model:

```
attr_accessible :package1_file_name, :package2_file_name
has_attached_file :package1
has_attached_file :package2
```

from my _form (simplified version):

```
<%= form_for(@submission, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "fileupload"  }) do |f| %>
 <%= f.file_field :package1%>
 <%= f.file_field :package2%>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that paperclip will insert two **separate** entries for each file in the database. 
However, I want it to insert into only **one** entries since I have two separate fields in my table: `package1_file_name`, `package2_file_name`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you!

---

For Christian Varga:

Maybe I shouldn't simplified the code in my original question, but my view actually look like this after using the `jQuery file upload` plugin:

```
<%= f.fields_for :uploads do |upload| %>
    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
        <!-- The first upload field -->
          <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                <%= upload.file_field :package1 %>
          </span>
        <!-- The second upload field -->
          <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                <%= upload.file_field :package2 %>
          </span>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Where `upload` is a child model of the current model

I am not sure whether the `multipart` makes the two file fields act like separate attachment, but I am trying to merge those two attachments into one.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so I've done a bit of research and I'm still unable to replicate your issue. I built a test application with that code, and it only inserts a single entry into the database.

Create Project (terminal)

```
rails new paperclip-test
cd paperclip-test
echo "gem 'paperclip'" >> Gemfile
bundle
rails generate scaffold submission
rails generate paperclip submission package1 package2
rake db:migrate
```

Update Model (**submission.rb**)

```
attr_accessible :package1, :package2
has_attached_file :package1, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
has_attached_file :package2, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
```

Update controller (**submissions_controller.rb**)

```
def create
    # @submission = Submission.new(params[:submission])
    @submission = Submission.create(params[:submission])
end
```

Update form (**_form.html.erb**)

```
<%= f.file_field :package1 %>
<%= f.file_field :package2 %>
```

Update view (**show.html.erb**)

```
<%= image_tag @submission.package1.url(:medium) %>
<%= image_tag @submission.package2.url(:medium) %>
```

Run app & create new submission

Go back to console:

```
sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3
select * from submissions;
```

Result:

```
1|2013-02-21 21:16:38.898602|2013-02-21 21:16:38.898602|image_1.jpg|image/jpeg|54231|2013-02-21 21:16:38.419947|image_2.jpg|image/jpeg|61766|2013-02-21 21:16:38.658720
```

Paperclip instructions from https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#quick-start

Comment: I think the problem is I am also using another plugin here :https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload